# Get center visible item of RecycleView when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

This is what I want:

[image]

As image above, I want to draw a center line on `RecycleView`, then get the center item when scrolling (as well as move left or right)
Here is my try to draw a horizontal `RecycleView`:

```
    HorizontalAdapter adapter = new HorizontalAdapter(data);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recycleView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Is there any way to know which item is moved to the center of `RecycleView`? And how can I scroll `RecycleView` to left or right just one position?

**Update**: I tried to use a scroll listener to get the middle position, but it doesn't work as an aspect.

```
  @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int firstPos = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastPos = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            int middle = Math.abs(lastPos - firstPos) / 2 + firstPos;

            int selectedPos = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
                if (i == middle) {
                    adapter.getItem(i).setSelected(true);
                    selectedPos = i;
                } else {
                    adapter.getItem(i).setSelected(false);
                }
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

And get the result:

[image]

I only want to change the selected item (make text to white color) when it is on the blue `Rect`

Comment: and what contains list_item_padding  layout can you tell me?? can you tell me

Comment: @MaheshSuthar it's just an empty layout with equal item width

Comment: sorry but its not working

Comment: can you tell me how to work same when user clicked on date and date will be on center??

Comment: @MaheshSuthar What have you tried? If it can't work, you should create another question. Try to read TranHieu's answer carefully, the algorithm is on this. I used  TranHieu's answer and customize to fit my need.

Comment: How did you got these navigation buttons work @R4j

Comment: @AmitKumarPawar as I remember, I assign current position whenever scroll the list. Then I increase/descrese position when press next/prev to find the next item, and use recycleview.scrollToPosition (or similiar method, don't remember exactly)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I made something just like this. I can do exactly what you need.
First of all, this is how is my alogrithm work
[image]

This is my recyclerView Adapter

```
public class DateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DateAdapter.DateViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<LabelerDate> dateDataList;


private static final int VIEW_TYPE_PADDING = 1;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 2;
private int paddingWidthDate = 0;

private int selectedItem = -1;

public DateAdapter(ArrayList<LabelerDate> dateData, int paddingWidthDate) {
    this.dateDataList = dateData;
    this.paddingWidthDate = paddingWidthDate;

}


@Override
public DateViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_date,
                parent, false);
        return new DateViewHolder(view);
    } else {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_padding,
                parent, false);

        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = paddingWidthDate;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new DateViewHolder(view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DateViewHolder holder, int position) {
    LabelerDate labelerDate = dateDataList.get(position);
    if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
        if(labelerDate.dateType.equals(BirthDayActivity.DateType.C31))
                holder.tvDate.setText(String.valueOf(labelerDate.valueDate));
                holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imgSmall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (position == selectedItem) {
            holder.tvDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#094673"));
            holder.tvDate.setTextSize(35);
            holder.imgSmall.setBackgroundResource(R.color.textviewbold);

        } else {
            holder.tvDate.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.tvDate.setTextSize(35);
            holder.imgSmall.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);
        }
    }
}

public void setSelecteditem(int selecteditem) {
    this.selectedItem = selecteditem;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dateDataList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    LabelerDate labelerDate = dateDataList.get(position);
    if (labelerDate.dateType.equals(BirthDayActivity.DateType.NONE)) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_PADDING;
    }
    return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
}


public class DateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvDate;
    public ImageView imgSmall;

    public DateViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNumberDate);
        imgSmall = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.small_marked_dob);
    }
}}
```

This is most important alogrithm:

```
public void getRecyclerviewDate() {
    recyclerViewDate = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewDay);
    ViewTreeObserver vtoDate = recyclerViewDate.getViewTreeObserver();
    vtoDate.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            recyclerViewDate.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            finalWidthDate = recyclerViewDate.getMeasuredWidth();
            itemWidthDate = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_dob_width);
            paddingDate = (finalWidthDate - itemWidthDate) / 2;
            firstItemWidthDate = paddingDate ;
            allPixelsDate = 0;

            final LinearLayoutManager dateLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            dateLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
            recyclerViewDate.setLayoutManager(dateLayoutManager);
            recyclerViewDate.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                    synchronized (this) {
                         if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){           
                            calculatePositionAndScrollDate(recyclerView);
                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    allPixelsDate += dx;
                }
            });
            if (labelerDates == null)
                labelerDates = new ArrayList<>();
            labelerDates.addAll(genLabelerDate(currentMonth, currentYear));
            dateAdapter = new DateAdapter(labelerDates, (int) firstItemWidthDate);
            recyclerViewDate.setAdapter(dateAdapter);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
/* this if most important, if expectedPositionDate < 0 recyclerView will return to nearest item*/

private void calculatePositionAndScrollDate(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    int expectedPositionDate = Math.round((allPixelsDate + paddingDate - firstItemWidthDate) / itemWidthDate);

    if (expectedPositionDate == -1) {
        expectedPositionDate = 0;
    } else if (expectedPositionDate >= recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 2) {
        expectedPositionDate--;
    }
    scrollListToPositionDate(recyclerView, expectedPositionDate);

}
/* this if most important, if expectedPositionDate < 0 recyclerView will return to nearest item*/
private void scrollListToPositionDate(RecyclerView recyclerView, int expectedPositionDate) {
    float targetScrollPosDate = expectedPositionDate * itemWidthDate + firstItemWidthDate - paddingDate;
    float missingPxDate = targetScrollPosDate - allPixelsDate;
    if (missingPxDate != 0) {
        recyclerView.smoothScrollBy((int) missingPxDate, 0);
    }
}
private void setDateValue() {
    int expectedPositionDateColor = Math.round((allPixelsDate + paddingDate - firstItemWidthDate) / itemWidthDate);
    setColorDate = expectedPositionDateColor + 1;
    //set color here
    dateAdapter.setSelecteditem(setColorDate);
}
 @Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);   
    allPixelsDate = savedInstanceState.getFloat(BUNDLE_LIST_PIXELS_DATE);
    allPixelsDateChanged = savedInstanceState.getFloat(BUNDLE_LIST_PIXELS_DATE_CHANGED);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putFloat(BUNDLE_LIST_PIXELS_DATE, allPixelsDate);
    outState.putFloat(BUNDLE_LIST_PIXELS_DATE_CHANGED, allPixelsDateChanged);
}
```

And this is my result:
[image]

Look at this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVvJUvFRkpU), this is my app demo

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. The `paddingDate` is never changed. So the formula `(allPixelsDate + paddingDate - firstItemWidthDate) / itemWidthDate` is equal to `allPixelsDate/itemWidthDate`, and return wrong selected position

Comment: well, I think the first Item's position in recyclerView (not a padding one) is 0, and it's Item is number 1. So that mean if you want to get right number Item you have to +1. I made it at setDateValue(). Tks for your respone

Comment: My items width is `100dp` and my middle item width is `200dp`. How i can implement this with different items width ?

Comment: @hema18 in my `onBindViewHolder` I have a variable called `selectedItem`. Just take a look at it. It will decide which item is in center.

Comment: I've watched the video, how can you change color and textsize during scroll by using RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE in OnScrollListener  @TranHieu

Comment: @tigikan You just need to look at my `onBindViewHolder`, I had object called `selectedItem`. That's mean recyclerview will detect which item is selected and change its item color.

Comment: @TranHieu it would be super cool if you make it a open source component at Github. Think about it :)

Comment: @PauloHenriqueNonaka thank you for your advice. I will consider about it. This source code still has a lot of issue. I'll make it better to become the open library soon

Comment: The screenshot came from an iOS device? That's kinda confusing.

Comment: It's pretty useless, as it does not support different widths of items

Comment: how can i do it for vertical Recyclerview ??

Comment: This code has been deprecated. If you guy still want to have my full source code. Please contact me via email hieubeta118@gmail.com. I'll give a full source code ASAP.

Comment: I don't understand what `R.layout. list_item_padding` represents.

Comment: This is a very expensive method because it is running Runnable

Comment: @TranHieu Can you please update the latest code. I am facing issue to change item color on scrolling. For now, I am able to achieve to change the centre item color when scrolling stops.

Comment: @Naina I'm sorry, this code has been deprecated for long time. You could search from github, there are some libs can do same thing like this one.

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes is needed the entire example code block together, because we may miss something. Here is what I have, feel free to correct anything since I may be doing some little mistake somewhere. And Yes, this answer is an extension of @tranhieu answer. Thanks @tranhieu.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public float firstItemWidthDate;
    public float paddingDate;
    public float itemWidthDate;
    public int allPixelsDate;
    public int finalWidthDate;
    private DateAdapter dateAdapter;
    private ArrayList<LabelerDate> labelerDates = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getRecyclerviewDate();

    }


    public void getRecyclerviewDate() {
        final RecyclerView recyclerViewDate = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_tasks_date);
        if (recyclerViewDate != null) {
            recyclerViewDate.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setDateValue();
                }
            }, 300);
            recyclerViewDate.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    recyclerViewDate.smoothScrollToPosition(dateAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
                    setDateValue();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
        ViewTreeObserver vtoDate = recyclerViewDate.getViewTreeObserver();
        vtoDate.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                recyclerViewDate.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                finalWidthDate = recyclerViewDate.getMeasuredWidth();
                itemWidthDate = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_dob_width);
                paddingDate = (finalWidthDate - itemWidthDate) / 2;
                firstItemWidthDate = paddingDate;
                allPixelsDate = 0;

                final LinearLayoutManager dateLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                dateLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
                recyclerViewDate.setLayoutManager(dateLayoutManager);
                recyclerViewDate.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                        synchronized (this) {
                            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                                calculatePositionAndScrollDate(recyclerView);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                        allPixelsDate += dx;
                    }
                });
                if (labelerDates == null) {
                    labelerDates = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                genLabelerDate();
                dateAdapter = new DateAdapter(labelerDates, (int) firstItemWidthDate);
                recyclerViewDate.setAdapter(dateAdapter);
                dateAdapter.setSelecteditem(dateAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void genLabelerDate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            LabelerDate labelerDate = new LabelerDate();
            labelerDate.setNumber(Integer.toString(i));
            labelerDates.add(labelerDate);

            if (i == 0 || i == 31) {
                labelerDate.setType(DateAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_PADDING);
            } else {
                labelerDate.setType(DateAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_ITEM);
            }
        }
    }
/* this if most important, if expectedPositionDate < 0 recyclerView will return to nearest item*/

    private void calculatePositionAndScrollDate(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        int expectedPositionDate = Math.round((allPixelsDate + paddingDate - firstItemWidthDate) / itemWidthDate);

        if (expectedPositionDate == -1) {
            expectedPositionDate = 0;
        } else if (expectedPositionDate >= recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 2) {
            expectedPositionDate--;
        }
        scrollListToPositionDate(recyclerView, expectedPositionDate);

    }

    /* this if most important, if expectedPositionDate < 0 recyclerView will return to nearest item*/
    private void scrollListToPositionDate(RecyclerView recyclerView, int expectedPositionDate) {
        float targetScrollPosDate = expectedPositionDate * itemWidthDate + firstItemWidthDate - paddingDate;
        float missingPxDate = targetScrollPosDate - allPixelsDate;
        if (missingPxDate != 0) {
            recyclerView.smoothScrollBy((int) missingPxDate, 0);
        }
        setDateValue();
    }

    //
    private void setDateValue() {
        int expectedPositionDateColor = Math.round((allPixelsDate + paddingDate - firstItemWidthDate) / itemWidthDate);
        int setColorDate = expectedPositionDateColor + 1;
//        set color here
        dateAdapter.setSelecteditem(setColorDate);
    }


    public class DateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DateAdapter.DateViewHolder> {
        private ArrayList<LabelerDate> dateDataList;


        private static final int VIEW_TYPE_PADDING = 1;
        private static final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 2;
        private int paddingWidthDate = 0;

        private int selectedItem = -1;

        public DateAdapter(ArrayList<LabelerDate> dateData, int paddingWidthDate) {
            this.dateDataList = dateData;
            this.paddingWidthDate = paddingWidthDate;

        }


        @Override
        public DateViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
                final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,
                    parent, false);
                return new DateViewHolder(view);
            } else {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,
                    parent, false);

                RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.width = paddingWidthDate;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                return new DateViewHolder(view);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(DateViewHolder holder, int position) {
            LabelerDate labelerDate = dateDataList.get(position);
            if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
                holder.tvDate.setText(labelerDate.getNumber());
                holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.d(TAG, "default " + position + ", selected " + selectedItem);
                if (position == selectedItem) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "center" + position);
                    holder.tvDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#76FF03"));
                    holder.tvDate.setTextSize(35);

                } else {
                    holder.tvDate.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    holder.tvDate.setTextSize(18);
                }
            } else {
                holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        public void setSelecteditem(int selecteditem) {
            this.selectedItem = selecteditem;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return dateDataList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            LabelerDate labelerDate = dateDataList.get(position);
            if (labelerDate.getType() == VIEW_TYPE_PADDING) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_PADDING;
            } else {
                return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
            }

        }


        public class DateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView tvDate;

            public DateViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tvDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date);
            }
        }
    }

    private class LabelerDate {
        private int type;
        private String number;

        public String getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(String number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_tasks_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_date"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/item_dob_width"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="32"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="item_dob_width">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: If i need to use Multiple Horizontal scroll view than?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820788/not-working-notifydatasetchange-on-recyclerview-with-center-selection-horizontal

Can you help me out on this

Comment: how can i do it for vertical Recyclerview ??

Answer (score 9):

Oh boy. I've been searching for this answer for almost a week and then found out the solution. Custom `LayoutManagers`? No. `ItemDecorator`? Nope.

Here's the easiest way to do it:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="150dp"
    android:paddingEnd="150dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

The critical part is:

```
    android:paddingStart="150dp"
    android:paddingEnd="150dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
```

And then just assign `SnapHelper` to your `RecylcerView`:

```
val snapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

This is it. The easiest and most perfect solution to the problem

Comment: This solution only works if the `RecyclerViewer` width and the first and last items' width is such that `150dp = RV.width * 0.5f - item.width * 0.5f`
If the item width changes in relation to the `RecyclerView` the first and last items will always be misaligned since this relies on using static widths for the RV and its items and expects them to always stay fixed. It is not a very good solution because of the total lack of flexibility.

Answer (score 5):

I'm used the SnapHelper right here:

```
    // init snaphelper        
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)

    // init layout manager
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mainActivity);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    // init adapter
    adatper.setSnapHelper(snapHelper);
    adatper.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adatper.initAdapter(new Float((DisplayHelper.getDisplayWidth(mainActivity) / 2) - (fooViewWidth / 2)).intValue());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adatper);
```

As said by TranHieu the solution of inserting 2 item for padding (at start and at end positions) is good.

I don't like the use of ViewTreeObserver because of poor readability of code. With this technique then you must also manage redrawing of the items if they are recycled.

If you are using customview classes you can set its width directly into these classes.

For example this is my padding class

```
/**
 * Created by firegloves on 25/09/15.
 */
@EViewGroup(R.layout.view_padding)
public class PaddingView extends FooView {

    Context mCtx;

    public PaddingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mCtx = context;
    }


    public void setWidth(int width) {
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

}
```

In my adapter I store the desired padding item width, that is equal to (displayWidth / 2) - (realItemWidth / 2)

This is my adapter, don't look at methods not matching RecyclerView.Adapter, pay attention to the initAdapter method and to the onCreateItemView method

```
@EBean
public class FooAdapterRecycler extends RecyclerViewAdapterBase<Foo, FooView> {

    private final int TYPE_PADDING_VIEW = 0;
    private final int TYPE_REAL_VIEW = 1;

    @RootContext
    Context ctx;
    @Bean(Finder.class)
    IFinder finder;

    SnapHelper snapHelper;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    private int paddingWidth = 0;

    /**
     * preleva i dati dal finder
     */
    public void initAdapter(int paddingWidth) {

        /*******************************
         * THIS CODE IS THE IMPORTANT ONE
         ******************************/

        this.paddingWidth = paddingWidth;

        // add 1 item for initial space
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        mItems.add(foo);

        // get real items from finder
        mItems.addAll(finder.findAll());

        // add 1 item for final space
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
        Foo foo2 = new Foo();
        mItems.add(foo2);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0 || position == getItemCount()-1) {
            return TYPE_PADDING_VIEW;
        } else {
            return TYPE_REAL_VIEW;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected FooView onCreateItemView(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        /*******************************
         * THIS CODE IS THE IMPORTANT ONE
         ******************************/

        if (viewType == TYPE_PADDING_VIEW) {
            PaddingView view = PaddingView_.build(ctx);
            view.setWidth(paddingWidth);
            return view;
        } else {
            return FooView_.build(ctx);
        }
    }

    public void setSnapHelper(SnapHelper snapHelper) {
        this.snapHelper = snapHelper;
    }

    public void setLayoutManager(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
    }
}
```

I'm using AndroidAnnotations library but it's not required

Hope that helps

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer? Like how to you tell what is the central item and change it's text color? And how do you initial set up the snapping if it's not perfectly aligned?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the other answer, there is no direct way to do this.

This is probably how you can achieve what you described in the question.

1. Know the number of items visible on the screen.
2. Select the middle item programmatically every time the view is scrolled.
3. Keep a partially transparent image as an overlay on the middle item on the recyclerview. (You'll need to compute the coordinates based on the width of the recycler view or width of the screen and the width of the overlay image you choose to put.
4. Refresh the selected value in a text view below the recycler view every time there is a scroll.

The image overlays have to be placed in a way they appear connected and as one single control.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand step 3 & 4. Could you provide some codes or examples to do that?

Comment: Point 3: I mean add an overlapping ImageView with transparent image of that shape. Sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754092/overlapping-imageview-in-relativeview

Comment: Point 4: I mean every time the user scrolls and the center value changes, progamatically select it, and put the selected date in the TextView, which would be another view below the recyclerview as seen in the gif you posted. I hope no code sample is required here. It is just about taking the selected value in recyclerview and putting it after formatting in the text view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820788/not-working-notifydatasetchange-on-recyclerview-with-center-selection-horizontal

Answer (score 3):

**USING SNAPHELPER - A SMOOTHER SOLUTION**

Here it is another solution using *SnapHelper*. Starting from the answer of @TranHieu here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34647005/3944251

and the compressed by @sector11 here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38411582/3944251

I wrote the following code which is also based in both answers above, but it's simpler and offers a smoother solution using SnapHelper presented in *android support library 24.2.0*.

Here you have the *MainActivity* class. The rest is the same with @sector11's answer.

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearSnapHelper;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public float firstItemWidthDate;
    public float itemWidthDate;
    public int allPixelsDate;
    public int finalWidthDate;
    private DateAdapter dateAdapter;
    private ArrayList<LabelerDate> labelerDates;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        labelerDates = new ArrayList<>();
        getRecyclerviewDate();

    }


    public void getRecyclerviewDate() {
        final RecyclerView recyclerViewDate = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_tasks_date);
        recyclerViewDate.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //recyclerViewDate.smoothScrollToPosition(dateAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
                setDateValue();
            }
        }, 300);
        ViewTreeObserver vtoDate = recyclerViewDate.getViewTreeObserver();
        vtoDate.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                recyclerViewDate.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                finalWidthDate = recyclerViewDate.getMeasuredWidth();
                itemWidthDate = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_dob_width);
                firstItemWidthDate = (finalWidthDate - itemWidthDate) / 2;
                allPixelsDate = 0;

                final LinearLayoutManager dateLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                dateLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
                recyclerViewDate.setLayoutManager(dateLayoutManager);

                /* Create a LinearSnapHelper and attach the recyclerView to it. */
                final LinearSnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
                snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewDate);

                recyclerViewDate.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                        allPixelsDate += dx;
                        recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                setDateValue();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                genLabelerDate();
                dateAdapter = new DateAdapter(labelerDates, (int) firstItemWidthDate);
                recyclerViewDate.setAdapter(dateAdapter);
                dateAdapter.setSelecteditem(dateAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void genLabelerDate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            LabelerDate labelerDate = new LabelerDate();
            labelerDate.setNumber(Integer.toString(i));
            labelerDates.add(labelerDate);

            if (i == 0 || i == 31) {
                labelerDate.setType(DateAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_PADDING);
            } else {
                labelerDate.setType(DateAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_ITEM);
            }
        }
    }

    //
    private void setDateValue() {
        int expectedPositionDateColor = Math.round(allPixelsDate / itemWidthDate);
        int setColorDate = expectedPositionDateColor + 1;
//        set color here
        dateAdapter.setSelecteditem(setColorDate);
    }


    public class DateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DateAdapter.DateViewHolder> {
        private ArrayList<LabelerDate> dateDataList;


        private static final int VIEW_TYPE_PADDING = 1;
        private static final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 2;
        private int paddingWidthDate = 0;

        private int selectedItem = -1;

        public DateAdapter(ArrayList<LabelerDate> dateData, int paddingWidthDate) {
            this.dateDataList = dateData;
            this.paddingWidthDate = paddingWidthDate;

        }


        @Override
        public DateAdapter.DateViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_PADDING) {
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.width = paddingWidthDate;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
            return new DateViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(DateAdapter.DateViewHolder holder, int position) {
            LabelerDate labelerDate = dateDataList.get(position);
            if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
                holder.tvDate.setText(labelerDate.getNumber());
                holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.d(TAG, "default " + position + ", selected " + selectedItem);
                if (position == selectedItem) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "center" + position);
                    holder.tvDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#76FF03"));
                    holder.tvDate.setTextSize(35);

                } else {
                    holder.tvDate.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    holder.tvDate.setTextSize(18);
                }
            } else {
                holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        public void setSelecteditem(int selecteditem) {
            this.selectedItem = selecteditem;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return dateDataList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            LabelerDate labelerDate = dateDataList.get(position);
            if (labelerDate.getType() == VIEW_TYPE_PADDING) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_PADDING;
            } else {
                return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
            }

        }


        public class DateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView tvDate;

            public DateViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tvDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date);
            }
        }
    }

    private class LabelerDate {
        private int type;
        private String number;

        public String getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(String number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the first item start from center. So, the last item. How to make first item to start from left and last item to right?

Comment: @Dionis, what is "item_db_width"?

Comment: I dont know what to give for "item_db_width". I just give 20 for it. And the center item get selected on initial load. while scrolling manually, the center item is not selected.

Comment: @Manikandan `item_dob_width` is the value defined in `item.xml` in @sector11's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38411582/3944251. Copy all `.xml` files from his answer and copy `MyActivity` code from my answer to have an idea how it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `LinearSnapHelper`

Attach to your recyclerView like

```
val snapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(this)
```

Then, to get the center view, use 
`snapHelper.findSnapView(horizontalScrollView.layoutManager)?`

Answer (score 1):

For this feature use EcoGallery library:
https://github.com/falnatsheh/EcoGallery

Comment: As of now - please don't use this as a solution, it was updated 7 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I needed something similar, not this. But I was able to adapt @TranHieu solution to my needs, so I voted up his solution.

**I wanted to create full-screen horizontal recyclerview that after user sroll updates scrollPosition to mostVisibleItem.**

setup:

```
private void setUpScrolling() {
    mRecyclerVIew.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            mRecyclerVIew.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            CustomScrollListener listener = (CustomScrollListener) mScrollListener;
            listener.width = mRecyclerVIew.getMeasuredWidth();
            listener.dx = 0;
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

listener:

```
private class CustomScrollListener extends OnScrollListener {
    private int mLastDx = 0;
    int width = 0;
    int dx = 0;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            if (mLastDx != dx) {
                scrollToMostVisibleItem();
            } else {
                dx = 0;
                mLastDx = 0;
            }
        }
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        this.dx += dx;
    }

    private void scrollToMostVisibleItem() {
        int direction = (dx > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        dx = Math.abs(dx);
        int shiftCount = Math.round(dx / width);
        int pixelShift = dx % width;
        if (pixelShift > width / 2) {
            shiftCount++;
        }

        float targetScrollPixels = shiftCount * width;
        float finalScrollPixels = (targetScrollPixels - dx) * direction;
        if (finalScrollPixels != 0) {
            mRecyclerVIew.smoothScrollBy((int) finalScrollPixels, 0);
            mLastDx = (int) finalScrollPixels;
            dx = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is mScrollListener ?

Answer (score 0):

I used another approach in my case.

you can find the deatils here: [RecyclerView - How highlight central visible item during scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942530/recyclerview-how-highlight-central-visible-item-during-scroll])[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942530/recyclerview-how-highlight-central-visible-item-during-scroll)

In my opinion, my solution is more easy than the others.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a more generic implementation, here is my code based on the answers of this thread:

Add the `CenterLinearSnapHelper`

```
public class CenterLinearSnapHelper extends LinearSnapHelper {

    //Constants
    public static final String TAG = CenterLinearSnapHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    //Attributes
    private Context context;
    private float itemWidth;
    private OnPaddingComputationListener listener;

    //Constructors

    /**
     * A linear snap helper which helps centering the items in a recyclerview.
     *
     * @param itemWidth The (fixed) width of a child view in pixels.
     */
    public CenterLinearSnapHelper(float itemWidth) {
        this.itemWidth = itemWidth;
    }

    public void attachToRecyclerView(@Nullable RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                     @NonNull OnPaddingComputationListener listener) throws IllegalStateException {
        this.listener = listener;

        //Calculates the padding for the first and end item
        calculatePadding(recyclerView);

        //Create a LinearSnapHelper and attach the recyclerView to it.
        attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public float getItemWidth() {
        return itemWidth;
    }

    private void calculatePadding(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView == null)
            return;

        ViewTreeObserver observer = recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                int finalWidth = recyclerView.getMeasuredWidth();
                float padding = (finalWidth - itemWidth) / 2;
                listener.onPadding(padding, finalWidth);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public interface OnPaddingComputationListener {
        void onPadding(float padding, int finalWidth);
    }

}
```

In your Activity/Fragment where you create your RecyclerView:

```
float itemWidth = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.favorite_room_width);
CenterLinearSnapHelper snapHelper = new CenterLinearSnapHelper(itemWidth);
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.listFavorites, (padding, finalWidth) -> {
    //Set the adapter
    roomAdapter = new RoomAdapter(requireContext(), rooms);
    roomAdapter.addPaddingItems((int) padding);
    roomAdapter.setOnToggleClickListener(FavoritesFragment.this);
    binding.listFavorites.setAdapter(roomAdapter);
});
```

In your adapter:

```
public void addPaddingItems(int padding) {
    if (padding < 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Padding cannot be smaller than 0");

    this.padding = padding;
    //Add 2 new items as the first and last
    //NOTE: If you update your existing dataset (e.g add new items), you should redo the calculation!
    rooms.add(0, new Room("First"));
    rooms.add(rooms.size(), new Room("Last"));
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (padding >= 0 && (position == 0 || position == rooms.size() - 1)) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_PADDING;
    }

    return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RoomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ViewFavoriteRoomBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.view_favorite_room, parent, false);

    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_PADDING) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) binding.getRoot().getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = padding;
        binding.getRoot().setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    RoomViewHolder viewHolder = new RoomViewHolder(context, binding, onToggleClickListener);
    viewHolder.getRecyclerView().setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);
    return viewHolder;
}
```