# How to set item to center of Recycler view when selected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a `RecyclerView` to display items horizontally. I want to set the selected item to center of the view like this

[image].

This is how I am doing it:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of what you wish to achieve and what you have tried thus far

Comment: try using `ViewPager` instead of RecyclerView.

Comment: @Ravi did you get any solution for this?

Comment: There is similar question. This answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34647005/5371091

Answer (score 12):

To obtain middle item on your screen from RecyclerView you can attach OnScrollListener to RecyclerView and inside listener you should get position of current items then you should check if area of given item is on middle of screen.

Code sample in Kotlin:

```
// Attach OnScrollListener to your RecyclerView
addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        recyclerView.post {
            selectMiddleItem()
        }
    }
})
```

```
// implementation of method that is called from OnScrollListener
private fun selectMiddleItem() {
    val firstVisibleIndex = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    val lastVisibleIndex = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
    val visibleIndexes = listOf(firstVisibleIndex..lastVisibleIndex).flatten()

    for (i in visibleIndexes) {
        val vh = findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i)
        if (vh?.itemView == null) {
            continue
        }
        val location = IntArray(2)
        vh.itemView.getLocationOnScreen(location)
        val x = location[0]
        val halfWidth = vh.itemView.width * .5
        val rightSide = x + halfWidth
        val leftSide = x - halfWidth
        val isInMiddle = screenWidth * .5 in leftSide..rightSide
        if (isInMiddle) {
            // "i" is your middle index and implement selecting it as you want 
            // optionsAdapter.selectItemAtIndex(i)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

And as result you should get something like this:

[image]

Comment: what is this ->? findViewHolderForLayoutPosition

Comment: @DPrince that's method from RecyclerView class. Check it out here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#findviewholderforlayoutposition

Comment: @NayMak in Android Studio you can convert automatically code from kotlin to java and vice-versa

Comment: what is this-> selectItemAtIndex @PawełKanarek

Comment: @PawełKanarek can you give me Details?

Comment: @BipinBharti that's method form my code that was responsible for changing color of view.

Comment: can you please share the whole code ?

Answer (score 8):

This is for snapping the item in the center when scrolling, or when clicking on an ite.

You need to have a SnapHelper added to the RecyclerView. Here is how:

```
final RecyclerView recyclerViewObject = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewObjectId);

final LinearSnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewObject);

recyclerViewObject.setOnFlingListener(snapHelper);
```

then you just call this code

```
recyclerViewObject.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), recyclerViewObject ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    recyclerViewObject.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
                }

                @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                }
            })
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve the same output with minimal lines of code. Where, **view** is view of selected adapter item and **StaticData.SCREEN_WIDTH** is device width.

```
    View view = rvCategory.getChildAt(pos);
    if (view == null)
        return;
    int scrollX = (view.getLeft() - (StaticData.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2)) + (view.getWidth() / 2);
    rvCategory.smoothScrollBy(scrollX, 0);
```

Comment: Use layout manager while getting view. Else it returns null.

val view: View? = headerRv.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(pos)

Answer (score 3):

Please try sort of this solution:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
int totalVisibleItems = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() - layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()    
int centeredItemPosition = totalVisibleItems / 2;
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
    recyclerView.setScrollY(centeredItemPosition );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: recyclerview doesnot have getLastVisiblePosition, getFirstVisiblePosition and smoothScrollByOffset is not available in recyclerView.

Comment: Thanks Saeed but, getLastVisiblePosition and getFirstVisiblePosition is not available in recyclerview.

Comment: @ravi those are `LayoutManager` methods

Comment: Side note:  If the views are different sizes, then this will not work exactly as expected.  It divides by 2 the number of children without taking into account the width of the children.  So you'll get the middle child, but you may not get the child in the center of the view.

Comment: I've posted upgraded version of your answer in case of different sizes of cells inside RecyclerView

Comment: recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position); which position ?

Comment: If I read this code well, this will place the top of the view in the middle of the screen, not view (its center) itself.

Answer (score 2):

Define your custom layout manager as

```
class CenterLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean) : super(context, orientation, reverseLayout)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

    override fun smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State, position: Int) {
        val centerSmoothScroller = CenterSmoothScroller(recyclerView.context)
        centerSmoothScroller.targetPosition = position
        startSmoothScroll(centerSmoothScroller)

    }

    private class CenterSmoothScroller(context: Context) : LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
        override fun calculateDtToFit(viewStart: Int, viewEnd: Int, boxStart: Int, boxEnd: Int, snapPreference: Int): Int = (boxStart + (boxEnd - boxStart) / 2) - (viewStart + (viewEnd - viewStart) / 2)
    }
}
```

Then assign this layout manager to your recycler view

```
myRecyclerview.layoutManager =
        CenterLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

In recyclerview's item onClick method use

```
myRecyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(position)
```

where position should get from onBindViewHolder

Also use LinearSnapHelper as

```
 val snapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(myRecyclerview)
```

it will controll scrolling effectively

Also attatch scroll listner to recyclerview to get item at center position

```
Recyclerview.setOnScrollListener(object:
            RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                var view=recyclerView[0]

            }
        })
```

[check out this stackoverflow answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654328/19091801)