# RecyclerView smoothScroll to position in the center. android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I am using a horizontal layout manager for my `RecyclerView`.
I need to make `RecyclerView` in the next way: when click on some item - make smoothScrool to that position and put that item in the center of `RecyclerView` (if it possible, for example, 10 item from 20).

So, I have no problem with `smoothScrollToPosition()`, but how to put item than in the center of `RecyclerView`???

Thanks!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

**Yes it's possible.**

By implementing `RecyclerView.SmoothScroller`'s method `onTargetFound(View, State, Action)`.

```
/**
 * Called when the target position is laid out. This is the last callback SmoothScroller
 * will receive and it should update the provided {@link Action} to define the scroll
 * details towards the target view.
 * @param targetView    The view element which render the target position.
 * @param state         Transient state of RecyclerView
 * @param action        Action instance that you should update to define final scroll action
 *                      towards the targetView
 */
abstract protected void onTargetFound(View targetView, State state, Action action);
```

Specifically in `LinearLayoutManager` with `LinearSmoothScroller`:

```
public class CenterLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public CenterLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CenterLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public CenterLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
        RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new CenterSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext());
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }

    private static class CenterSmoothScroller extends LinearSmoothScroller {

        CenterSmoothScroller(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int calculateDtToFit(int viewStart, int viewEnd, int boxStart, int boxEnd, int snapPreference) {
            return (boxStart + (boxEnd - boxStart) / 2) - (viewStart + (viewEnd - viewStart) / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `extends LinearSmoothScroller `must override `computeScrollVectorForPosition()`

Comment: Worked flawless

Comment: Perfect, for others, you just call         `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);` and don't forget to set the layout manager `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

Comment: Where is that `onTargetFound()` function implemented?

Comment: But I did not understood exactly why you mentioned about this method `onTargetFound()` ?

Comment: when call smoothScrollToPosition height all item decrease, why?

Comment: Thank god in heaven you saved me

Comment: A Perfect Solution Indeed. But, it's still not smooth enough. Is there a way to make it smoother ?

Answer (score 65):

**Improvements to the answer -** there is no need to override the `LinearLayoutManager`

From the previous answer:

```
public class CenterSmoothScroller extends LinearSmoothScroller {

    public CenterSmoothScroller(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int calculateDtToFit(int viewStart, int viewEnd, int boxStart, int boxEnd, int snapPreference) {
        return (boxStart + (boxEnd - boxStart) / 2) - (viewStart + (viewEnd - viewStart) / 2);
    }
}
```

Here how to use it:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = new GridLayoutManager(...): // or whatever layout manager you need

...

RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new CenterSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext());

smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);

lm.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
```

Comment: For others who are confused like I was, `CenterSmoothScroller` is a class found in the accepted answer.

Comment: Hallelujah! Spent half a day trying a bunch of convoluted ways to do this and your solution works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: How will I get the position while declaring the recyclerview? I need to get the item in center while the user scrolls the item using D-Pad. @user8944115

Comment: this worked like a charm!! thanks if you don't find the class maybe you need update your dependencies, is under `androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearSmoothScroller`

Comment: It's correct and easy solution. Thanks

Comment: For me, this doesnt work for the first and the last item in the recycler. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This method just slides an item to the center like a finger, so it is impossible to achieve the first or last item, just like your finger cannot do it.

Answer (score 18):

Just in case someone needs the **Kotlin equivalent** of the class in the accepted answer.

```
class CenterLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean) : super(context, orientation, reverseLayout)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

    override fun smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State, position: Int) {
        val centerSmoothScroller = CenterSmoothScroller(recyclerView.context)
        centerSmoothScroller.targetPosition = position
        startSmoothScroll(centerSmoothScroller)
    }

    private class CenterSmoothScroller(context: Context) : LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
        override fun calculateDtToFit(viewStart: Int, viewEnd: Int, boxStart: Int, boxEnd: Int, snapPreference: Int): Int = (boxStart + (boxEnd - boxStart) / 2) - (viewStart + (viewEnd - viewStart) / 2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Boda's answer, if you want to control smooth scroll speed (for better animation) you can use below:

```
class CenterLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean) : super(
        context,
        orientation,
        reverseLayout
    )

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr,
        defStyleRes
    )

    override fun smoothScrollToPosition(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State,
        position: Int
    ) {
        val centerSmoothScroller = CenterSmoothScroller(recyclerView.context)
        centerSmoothScroller.targetPosition = position
        startSmoothScroll(centerSmoothScroller)
    }

    private class CenterSmoothScroller(context: Context) : LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
        override fun calculateDtToFit(
            viewStart: Int,
            viewEnd: Int,
            boxStart: Int,
            boxEnd: Int,
            snapPreference: Int
        ): Int = (boxStart + (boxEnd - boxStart) / 2) - (viewStart + (viewEnd - viewStart) / 2)

        override fun calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics): Float {
            return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi
        }
    }

    companion object {
        // This number controls the speed of smooth scroll
        private const val MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 150f
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = CenterLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(selectedPosition)
```

Answer (score -3):

since now(Feb 2019), I could easily use this code in ListView

```
(ListView)word_list_view.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(your_item_index, center_position.y);
```

RecyclerView not verified, I guess would be the same.

Comment: Not available for RecyclerView