# layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() with a horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I am coding an Android application for a school project.

I have implemented a `RecyclerView` with horizontal scroll using `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`.

I would like to make it such that a specific element, for example element n, is in **the middle** of the set of currently visible elements, like so:
[image]

I have searched around, and found this link: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3o0xzw/how_do_you_scroll_to_an_item_with_recyclerview_to/

The solution involved taking half the sum of `layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` and `layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()` and adding it to the position of the element you want to be in the middle.

However, these two methods always returned `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` when I used this horizontally scrolling `RecyclerView`, hence half the sum would be 0, and it would render the calculation useless.

Here is my code:

```
RecyclerView selectDay = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lv_selectDay);
    daySelectorAdapter adapter = new daySelectorAdapter(this, arrayList);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    selectDay.setAdapter(adapter);
    selectDay.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    int firstVisible = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    Log.d("FIRSTVISIBLE", String.valueOf(firstVisible)); // returns -1

    int lastVisible = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    Log.d("LASTVISIBLE", String.valueOf(lastVisible)); // also -1

    int halfScreenOffset = (lastVisible - firstVisible) / 2;
    Log.d("HALFOFFSET", String.valueOf(halfScreenOffset));

    layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset((15 + halfScreenOffset), 0);
```

May I know if anyone has a workaround to this problem? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: When I tried implementing a `onScrollListener` and cast `recyclerView.getLayoutManager()` to `LinearLayoutManager`, these methods worked perfectly fine. May I know why?**

**EDIT 2:**

**I used this solution right here: [RecyclerView smoothScroll to position in the center. android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416146/recyclerview-smoothscroll-to-position-in-the-center-android), However why do the methods return `NO_POSITION`?**

Comment: RecyclerView works asynchronously. You need to wait for the RecyclerView items to be laid out before findFirstVisibleItemPosition() will return a valid result.

Comment: Ah. I see. Thanks.