# get item with current date in recycleView (without OnClick)

Tags: android, kotlin

I make a calendar in one line. I am using recyclerview. How can I track the position of the current date to show it in the center of the screen?
Right now it shows first day of month

> This is what it is showing now

[image: Calendar stating from 1st date]

> And below is the needed one

[image: Need to start from current date range]

```
class DateAdapter(private val dateList: List<Calendar>, val currentDate: String):
                RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>(){

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
                val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.date_layout, parent,  false)

                val holder = MyViewHolder(parent)


                return holder
            }

            override fun getItemCount(): Int {
                return dateList.count()
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

                holder?.setData(currentDate, dateList, position)
                Log.d(TAG,holder.layoutPosition.toString())
            }
        }
```

**# MyViewHolder #**

```
        class MyViewHolder(private val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

    fun setData(currentDate: String, dateList: List<Calendar>, position: Int){
        if(currentDate == dateList[position].get(Calendar.DATE).toString()){
            view?.str_day_element?.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            view?.num_day_element?.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)

            view?.str_day_element?.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(view.context,R.color.blue800))
            view?.num_day_element?.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(view.context,R.color.blue800))

        }
        else{
            view?.str_day_element?.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(view.context,R.color.gray700))
            view?.num_day_element?.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(view.context,R.color.gray700))

            view?.str_day_element?.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            view?.num_day_element?.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        }
        val dayOfWeekInMonth: Int = dateList[position].get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        var dayOfWeekInMonthStr = ""
        when(dayOfWeekInMonth-1) {
            1 -> dayOfWeekInMonthStr = "Пн"
            2 -> dayOfWeekInMonthStr = "Вт"
            3 -> dayOfWeekInMonthStr = "Ср"
            4 -> dayOfWeekInMonthStr = "Чт"
            5 -> dayOfWeekInMonthStr = "Пт"
            6 -> dayOfWeekInMonthStr = "Сб"
            0 -> dayOfWeekInMonthStr = "Вс"
        }
        view?.str_day_element?.text = dayOfWeekInMonthStr
        view?.num_day_element?.text = dateList[position].get(Calendar.DATE).toString()
    }

}
```

**init single row calendar**

```
fun InitLittleCalendar(){
        var date = Calendar.getInstance()
        val numDay = date.get(Calendar.DATE).toString()
        singleRowCalendar.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        singeRowCalendar.adapter = DateAdapter(GetDaysList(), numDay)
        singeRowCalendar.addOnScrollListener(CustomScrollListener())
    }
```

**function for getting a list of dates of the month**

```
fun GetDaysList(): List<Calendar> {

    val readOnlyView =  mutableListOf<Calendar>()
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val days = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    var index = 0
    while(index < days){
        readOnlyView += getDaysPlus(index)
        index++
    }
    return readOnlyView
}
```

**increment day**

```
fun getDaysPlus(daysAgo: Int): Calendar {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +daysAgo)

    return calendar
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code for RV adapter that you use

Comment: @MarošŠeleng Update question

Comment: What is your Calendar model and ViewHolder implementation looks like?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman added what you requested

Comment: So basically, the highlighting part is done? You just need to scroll to the position? If that's the case, you should use `smoothScrollToPosition` method on the RecyclerView or possibly, to center it using method shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416146/recyclerview-smoothscroll-to-position-in-the-center-android.

Comment: @MarošŠeleng thanks, I will try to implement using smoothScrollToPosition