# Not working Notifydatasetchange on RecyclerView with center selection Horizontal Scrollview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, material-design, horizontalscrollview

Auto Scrolling is issue & also move to some specific position using code is difficult.

I am making two recyclerView dependent to each other with the Horizontal Scroll and center selection.

So my problem is using the method of Notifydatasetchanged and reseting recyclerView postion to 0 and it's scrolling selection range because it's returning wrong index...

When i want to get center selection index after changing data.
I am using below example to achieve this with some edits.

[Get center visible item of RecycleView when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586637/get-center-visible-item-of-recycleview-when-scrolling)

I need to change the data on scroll of First recyclerView Adapter to second recyclerView Adapter with data change.

But scrollview set the position in first position
I tried the  notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)
notifyItemRangeInserted(int, int) methods...

Detail Explanation : I am changing the type and reset the value of Look scrollview. I need to change the selected position of bottom scrollview. Specially I can't get the center position by changing data. Means I if i am notifying the adapter than index will remain as it is. I need to do work it like normal adapter after reset data.

Thanks in advance.

```
   public void getRecyclerview_Type() {

    final RecyclerView recyclerView_Type = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    if (recyclerView_Type != null) {
        recyclerView_Type.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setTypeValue();
            }
        }, 300);
        recyclerView_Type.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // recyclerView_Type.smoothScrollToPosition(Type_Adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                setTypeValue();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
    ViewTreeObserver treeObserver = recyclerView_Type.getViewTreeObserver();
    treeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            recyclerView_Type.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            finalWidthDate = recyclerView_Type.getMeasuredWidth();
            itemWidthDate = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_dob_width_padding);
            paddingDate = (finalWidthDate - itemWidthDate) / 2;
            firstItemWidthDate = paddingDate;
            allPixelsDate = 0;

            final LinearLayoutManager dateLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            dateLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
            recyclerView_Type.setLayoutManager(dateLayoutManager);
            recyclerView_Type.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                    synchronized (this) {
                        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            calculatePositionAndScroll_Type(recyclerView);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    allPixelsDate += dx;
                }
            });
            if (mTypeBeanArrayList == null) {
                mTypeBeanArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            getMedicationType();
            Type_Adapter = new Medication_Type_RecyclerAdapter(Add_Reminder_medicationlook_Activity.this, mTypeBeanArrayList, (int) firstItemWidthDate);
            recyclerView_Type.setAdapter(Type_Adapter);
            Type_Adapter.setSelecteditem(Type_Adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void getMedicationType() {

    for (int i = 0; i < mTypeBeanArrayList.size(); i++) {
        Medication_TypeBean medication_typeBean = mTypeBeanArrayList.get(i);


        Log.print("Image name :" +medication_typeBean.getType_image_name());
        if (i == 0 || i == (mTypeBeanArrayList.size() - 1)) {
            medication_typeBean.setType(VIEW_TYPE_PADDING);
        } else {
            medication_typeBean.setType(VIEW_TYPE_ITEM);
        }
        mTypeBeanArrayList.set(i, medication_typeBean);

    }
}
```

/* this if most important, if expectedPositionDate < 0 recyclerView will return to nearest item*/

```
private void calculatePositionAndScroll_Type(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    int expectedPositionDate = Math.round((allPixelsDate + paddingDate - firstItemWidthDate) / itemWidthDate);

    if (expectedPositionDate == -1) {
        expectedPositionDate = 0;
    } else if (expectedPositionDate >= recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 2) {
        expectedPositionDate--;
    }
    scrollListToPosition_Type(recyclerView, expectedPositionDate);

}

/* this if most important, if expectedPositionDate < 0 recyclerView will return to nearest item*/
private void scrollListToPosition_Type(RecyclerView recyclerView, int expectedPositionDate) {
    float targetScrollPosDate = expectedPositionDate * itemWidthDate + firstItemWidthDate - paddingDate;
    float missingPxDate = targetScrollPosDate - allPixelsDate;
    if (missingPxDate != 0) {
        recyclerView.smoothScrollBy((int) missingPxDate, 0);
    }
    setTypeValue();

}

private void setTypeValue() {
    int expectedPositionDateColor = Math.round((allPixelsDate + paddingDate - firstItemWidthDate) / itemWidthDate);
    int setColorDate = expectedPositionDateColor + 1;

    Type_Adapter.setSelecteditem(setColorDate);
    mTxt_type_name.setText(mTypeBeanArrayList.get(setColorDate).getMedication_type_name());

    mSELECTED_TYPE_ID = setColorDate;

    //NotifyLookChangetoType(setColorDate);
}
```

//Type Adapter

```
 public class Medication_Type_RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Medication_Type_RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Medication_TypeBean> medication_typeBeanArrayList;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_PADDING = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 2;
    private int paddingWidthDate = 0;
    private Context mContext;
    private int selectedItem = -1;

    public Medication_Type_RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Medication_TypeBean> dateData, int paddingWidthDate) {
        this.medication_typeBeanArrayList = dateData;
        this.paddingWidthDate = paddingWidthDate;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_medication_type,
                    parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_medication_type,
                    parent, false);
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = paddingWidthDate;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Medication_TypeBean medication_typeBean = mTypeBeanArrayList.get(position);
        if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            // holder.mTxt_Type.setText(medication_typeBean.getMedication_type_name());
            //holder.mTxt_Type.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mImg_medication.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            int d = R.drawable.ic_type_pill;
            try {
                //Due to Offline requirements we do code like this get the images from our res folder

                if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_pill")) {
                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_pill;
                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_patch")) {
                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_patch;
                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_capsule")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_capsule;

                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_ring")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_ring;

                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_inhaler")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_inhaler;


                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_spray")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_spray;


                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_bottle")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_bottle;

                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_drop")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_drop;


                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_pessaries")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_pessaries;

                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_sachets")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_sachets;


                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_tube")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_tube;


                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_suppository")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_suppository;

                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_injaction")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_injaction;

                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_spoon")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_spoon;

                } else if (medication_typeBean.getType_image_name().equalsIgnoreCase("ic_type_powder")) {

                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_powder;

                } else {
                    d = R.drawable.ic_type_pill;
                }

                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                        d);
                holder.mImg_medication.setImageBitmap(icon);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.print(e);
            }


            //     BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), icon);
            //  img.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
            // holder.mImg_medication.setBackground(ob);

            // Log.print("Type Adapter", "default " + position + ", selected " + selectedItem);
            if (position == selectedItem) {
                Log.print("Type adapter", "center" + position);
                //  holder.mTxt_Type.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#76FF03"));
                //holder.mImg_medication.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN);
                //   holder.mTxt_Type.setTextSize(35);
                holder.mImg_medication.getLayoutParams().height = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_dob_width) + 10;
                holder.mImg_medication.getLayoutParams().width = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_dob_width) + 10;
            } else {
                holder.mImg_medication.getLayoutParams().height = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_dob_width) - 10;
                holder.mImg_medication.getLayoutParams().width = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_dob_width) - 10;
                //  holder.mTxt_Type.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                //holder.mImg_medication.setColorFilter(null);
                //  holder.mTxt_Type.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                // holder.mTxt_Type.setTextSize(18);
                //   holder.mImg_medication.getLayoutParams().height = 70;
                //   holder.mImg_medication.getLayoutParams().width = 70;
            }
        } else {
            holder.mImg_medication.getLayoutParams().height = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_dob_width) - 10;
            holder.mImg_medication.getLayoutParams().width = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_dob_width) - 10;
            //  holder.mTxt_Type.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.mImg_medication.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void setSelecteditem(int selecteditem) {
        this.selectedItem = selecteditem;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (medication_lookBeanArrayList != null && Look_Adapter != null) {
            NotifyLookChangetoType(selecteditem);
        }
    }

    public int getSelecteditem() {
        return selectedItem;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return medication_typeBeanArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Medication_TypeBean medication_typeBean = medication_typeBeanArrayList.get(position);
        if (medication_typeBean.getType() == VIEW_TYPE_PADDING) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_PADDING;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //public TextView mTxt_Type;
        public ImageView mImg_medication;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //  mTxt_Type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mTxt);
            mImg_medication = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mImg_medication);
        }
    }
}

//Type Adapter ends ************************************************
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Do you want the top list to scroll to the same position as the bottom list? When do you want the top list to change its selected position?

Comment: I am changing the type and reset the value of Look scrollview.
I need to change the selected position of bottom scrollview.
Specially I can't get the center position by changing data.
Means I if i am notifying the adapter than index will remain as it is.
I need to do work it like normal adapter after reset data.

Comment: @Caleb : I explain the case in detail.can you check it now

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get you properly but you want to change the data of one recyclerview and reset the value of other recyclerview

Try using recyclerView.scrollToPosition(INDEX_YOU_WANT_TO_SCROLL_TO);

IF YOU WANT TO ACHIEVE THE CENTER POSTION OF THE DATA USE
       recyclerview.scrollToPosition(arraylist.size()/2);
arrayList in which your drawable data is stored