# cardview shadow elevation animation in recyclerview

Tags: android, animation, android-cardview, android-elevation

I want `cardview` `elevation` animation just like Google is doing in "PlayGames" animation. Here is a sample `gif` of animation. Can anyone guide me how to do it or refer any library.

[sample gif animation](https://giphy.com/gifs/3ohs81s1w0p0sJBpNm)

Thanks

Comment: this library may help https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to do it?** 
Using Viewpager and Shadow Transform

1- create a `PagerAdapter`  for cardview

2- inside the adapter in `instantiateItem` method set elevation for the card like this

```
 CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        if (mBaseElevation == 0) {
            mBaseElevation = cardView.getCardElevation();
        }

        cardView.setMaxCardElevation(mBaseElevation * MAX_ELEVATION_FACTOR);
        mViews.set(position, cardView);
        return view;
```

after that implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` 
inside the `onPageScrolled`

```
        if (currentCard != null) {
            if (mScalingEnabled) {
                currentCard.setScaleX((float) (1 + 0.1 * (1 - realOffset)));
                currentCard.setScaleY((float) (1 + 0.1 * (1 - realOffset)));
            }
            currentCard.setCardElevation((baseElevation + baseElevation
                    * (CardAdapter.MAX_ELEVATION_FACTOR - 1) * (1 - realOffset)));
        }

        CardView nextCard = mAdapter.getCardViewAt(nextPosition);

        // We might be scrolling fast enough so that the next (or previous) card
        // was already destroyed or a fragment might not have been created yet
        if (nextCard != null) {
            if (mScalingEnabled) {
                nextCard.setScaleX((float) (1 + 0.1 * (realOffset)));
                nextCard.setScaleY((float) (1 + 0.1 * (realOffset)));
            }
            nextCard.setCardElevation((baseElevation + baseElevation
                    * (CardAdapter.MAX_ELEVATION_FACTOR - 1) * (realOffset)));
        }
```

full code [ViewPagerCards](https://github.com/rubensousa/ViewPagerCards)

if you want to do that using `RecyclerView`
you can get the middle item and check `onBindViewHolder` if that item is middle item then do the scale animation 
to know to get the middle check this answer :
[Get center visible item of RecycleView when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586637/get-center-visible-item-of-recycleview-when-scrolling)

Comment: this solution works well but I can scroll only one position at a time with viewpager. I can't handle fling that's why I wanted to do it with recyclerview

Comment: @HiteshBisht I've updated the answer to make it work with RececlerView, let me know if it helped you!

Comment: I am already doing this using SnapHelper class in android but now I also want the scaling and elevation to work while the user is scrolling like I have shown in the sample GIF. Thank you

Comment: You can do the scaling and the elevation on bindview with the cardview code above whats is missing?